# Double actions in Receiver

Tags: java, android, annotations, android-annotations

I receive 2 action like below:

```
@Receiver (actions = MY_ACTION)
protected void myMethod(){
methodA();
}

@Receiver (actions = MY_ACTION_SECOND)
protected void myMethod(){
methodA();
}
```

Is it possible to set 2 different ACTION in 1 receiver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Receiver` accepts an array of actions:

```
@Receiver(actions = {MY_ACTION, MY_ACTION_SECOND})
void myMethod(){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED**

Try:

```
@Receiver ({actions = MY_ACTION, actions = MY_ACTION_SECOND})
protected void myMethod(){
    methodA();
}
```

Comment: "Duplicate annotations"

Comment: You can't use the same annotation twice

Comment: it's not same annotation, there are different broadcast

Comment: Updated doesn't even compile